# What is the purpose of wrapped values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monad

I've recently read [an article](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) about Functors, Applicatives and Monads in Haskell and it concludes with these statements:

- functors: you apply a function to a wrapped value using `fmap` or `<$>`
- applicatives: you apply a wrapped function to a wrapped value using `<*>` or `liftA`
- monads: you apply a function that returns a wrapped value, to a wrapped value using `>>=` or `liftM`

This is all clear but I don't get what the purpose of the a *wrapped value* is. Do they work like the decorators in python or the `Optional` in java? I would greatly appreciate some practical example from the real world.

Comment: Yes, `Optional` in Java is one such example of a "wrapper". What a wrapper (like a Functor) is, is more or less explained in the article you linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java's `Optional` is essentially equivalent to Haskell's `Maybe` monad, so that's a good starting place for understanding how these "wrapped values" behave.

`Functors`, `Applicatives` and `Monads` are ways of modelling some kind of additional behavior that can modify an existing type. `Maybe` takes a type, and modifies it so that it can model both a *one single instance* or *no instance* of that type. `List` modifies a type so that it models a sequence of instances of the given type.

Each of these typeclasses provides a way to apply a given function to the wrapped type, respecting the modifications that the wrapping type makes. For example, in Haskell,

#### Functors

Functors use the `fmap` or `<$>` functions (different names for the same thing):

- `fmap` or `<$>` `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

This takes a function and applies to to the wrapped elements

```
fmap (\x -> x + 1) (Just 1)   -- Applies (+1) to the inner value, returning (Just 2)
fmap (\x -> x + 1) Nothing    -- Applies (+1) to an empty wrapper, returning Nothing

fmap (\x -> x + 1) [1, 2, 3]  -- Applies (+1) to all inner values, returning [2, 3, 4]
(\x -> x + 1) <$> [1, 2, 3]   -- Same as above
```

#### Applicatives

Applicatives use the `<*>` function:

- `<*>` `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

This takes a **wrapped** function and applies it to the wrapped elements

```
(Just (\x -> x + 1)) <*> (Just 1) -- Returns (Just 2)
(Just (\x -> x + 1)) <*> Nothing  -- Returns Nothing
Nothing <*> (Just 1)              -- Returns Nothing
[(*2), (*4)] <*> [1, 2]           -- Returns [2, 4, 4, 8]
```

#### Monads

There are two relevant functions in the Monad typeclass:

- `return` `Monad m => a -> m a`
- `(>>=)` `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` (pronounced "bind")

The `return` function bears no resemblance to the one you may be familiar with in C-style languages. It takes a raw, unwrapped value, and wraps it up in the desired monadic type.

```
makeJust :: a -> Maybe a
makeJust x = return x

let foo = makeJust 10 -- returns (Just 10)
```

The bind function lets you temporarily unwrap the inner elements of a Monad and pass them to a function that performs some action that wraps them back UP in the same monad. This can be used with the `return` function in trivial cases:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] >>= (\x -> return (x + 1))  -- Returns [2, 3, 4, 5]
(Just 1) >>= (\x -> return (x + 1))      -- Returns (Just 2)
Nothing >>= (\x -> return (x + 1))       -- Returns Nothing
```

Where it gets interesting is when you have functions to chain together that don't require you to use `return`. I like to use `getLine` and `putStrLn` as examples, which have the following signatures using the `IO` monad:

- `getLine` `IO String`
- `putStrLn` `String -> IO ()`

You can call these functions like so:

```
getLine >>= (\x -> putStrLn x) -- Gets a line from IO and prints it to the console
getLine >>= putStrLn -- With currying, this is the same as above
```

You could also use the `>>=` function to chain a few operations together.

```
-- Reads a line from IO, converts to a number, adds 10 and prints it
getLine >>= (return . read) >>= (return . (+10)) >>= putStrLn . show
```

Comment: What you describe has some resemblance to python decorators or the decorator pattern in java but this seems more elegant to me since the Nothing is implicitly checked and no boilerplate is needed. Right?

Comment: @AdamArold They're not totally dissimilar. It's hard to properly describe how things like Monads work because they work on a _very_ abstract and generic level, and can have any number of very different uses. They basically just do "something" to change how a type behaves, without having to know anything specific about the type that they're working on.

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to say. So the difference to say a java decorator is that this is a more abstract decorator where I get an `Object` and I can do whatever I want with that `Object` which can be even a `FunctionalInterface` or such.

Comment: @AdamArold Keeping in mind that in Haskell, you don't have a base `Object` type. Haskell's brand of polymorphism is mostly via **Parametric Polymorphism** (equivalent to Generics in Java). This means that you don't have to lose type information (by casting to something more general like `Object`) when wrapping up a type in a Monad. In fact, Monads can't be properly represented in Java, because they require *Higher Kinded Types* - a generic type whose definition includes another generic type. Hence the `(Monad m) => m a` you see up there. Both `m` and `a` are generic.

Comment: I've read up on Higher Kinded Types. So basically using them I can get rid of the excessive call to `isPresent` for example since the use case of `Nothing` is already handled in the typeclass definition which can be in fact a monad?

Comment: Might be worth adding that the value of `Applicative` is that you can apply functions of multiple arguments, e.g., `((\x y z -> x + y + z) <$> Just 5 <*> Just 10 <*> Just 200) == Just 215`. Also, in `x >>= y`, the result of `y` can depend on the result of `x`, so they must be evaluated serially; whereas with `x <*> y`, the two are independent and can be evaluated concurrently, e.g., with the `Concurrently` applicative.

Answer (score 3):

That article has the virtue of being very visual and intuitive... but at the cost of building intuitions that are often false.  The concepts of functor, applicative and monad do not require you to have "wrapped" values, strictly speaking.

One good example to consider here is the concept of **promises** that's been gaining traction recently (particularly in Javascript).  A promise, in this sense, is an object that acts as a placeholder for the result value of an asynchronous, background computation, like fetching some data from a remote service.  In addition to that, it serves as a **mediator** between the asynchronous computation and functions that need to operate on its anticipated result.

Promise libraries usually support a functorial/monadic API where you can "chain" a function onto a promise, which produces another promise that produces the result of applying that function to the original promise's result.

This provides a vivid example of the value of the functor/monad interface, because the whole point of promises is that they allow you to say what function should apply to the result of a background task, **before that task has completed**.  When you `map` a function over a promise, the value that your function should apply to *may not have been computed yet* (and in fact, if there is an error somewhere it may never be computed).

More generally, you can think of functor/applicative/monad as interfaces for **mediator** objects that sit in between functions and arguments, and connect them indirectly according to some policy.  The simplest way to use a function is just to call it with some arguments; but if you have first-class functions, you have other, indirect options—you can supply the function to a mediator object that will control if, when and how many times the function will be called, and what to do with its result.  Promises are one such example:

1. They call the functions supplied to them when the result of some background task is completed
2. The results of those functions are then handed over to other promises that are waiting for them.

Answer (score 2):

Well Optional is a monad (and therfore an applicative functor and a functor), and indeed many container types are monadic as well, and people usually have a fairly good intuition for how containery type things work as these things, as I believe you do from your question.

However lots of things that aren't normally thought of as containers can also be monads, applicative or functors e.g. parsers combinators or IO or writing to a log. An alternative way of looking at them is as computations in some context, for instance, while List is obviously a container of values you can also consider computations in the List monad as representing [nondeterministic computations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638893/how-can-non-determinism-be-modeled-with-a-list-monad)

What I'm leading up to here is that monads are intrinsictly more abstract than the examples you are after. they are literally:

- a type constructor
- a return/unit function
- and a bind (or join and fmap) function

that satisfy the 3 [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws), there is no further unifying principle than that (for a monad, replace with relevant functions and laws for Applicative and Functor)

Comment: So what is the difference between a monad and a decorator then?

Comment: at the very least i'd think the static/dynamic divide is a difference between them, but I don't know enough python to know if there are any other implications

Comment: on the Java side, as I said Optional in a monad but as a pattern only, Java lacks the power in its type system to write a function that can operate on any monad